# How can we write multiple column search with the help of laravel and mongo?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In my laravel project, I have search field in listing page to search `email`, `firstname` and `lastname` but when I type `firstname` and `lastname` sometimes result is not getting. Database I am using is mongo. I am using a package to connect mongo "https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb". I think for better result we need to use raw method right? If so how can I add mongo query with raw(). Please help me I am a beginner in mongo.

```
$users     = Userlist::select('_id', 'usrEmail', 'usrFirstname', 'usrLastname')
                        ->where(function($query) use ($search) {
                            $query->where('usrEmail', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                                ->orWhere('usrFirstname', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                                ->orWhere('usrLastname', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                        })
                        ->skip($start)
                        ->take($limit)
                        ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Explain what "not getting" means. My perception is quite basically that `"John Smith"` simply does not exist in any of the fields being searched. Rather you want `"John", "Smith"` as **two separate terms** which again basically make their own `$or` condition. Pretty sure that sort of "dynamic" query building is supported in the laravel query builder without resorting to "raw". But the main problem is you **first** need to separate the "two" strings. Rather than send them as **one**, as you are presently doing.

Comment: not getting means, When I search `usrFirstname` is `John`, I am not getting user details of john (`'_id', 'usrEmail', 'usrFirstname', 'usrLastname'`).